# Do meals made with booze quench thirst?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I had like 50 "dwarven ale roast" (lavish meals), but my dwarves kept dying from thirst (in a map with no water). Maybe the alcohol was used only for the sauce!

Is this intended? Should I simply forbid booze for cooking, if I'm low on production?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, food made from booze does not quench thirst, it sates hunger. If you're afraid of running out of booze, disallow it to be cooked, otherwise it's a great way to create massive stacks of fairly high-value food.